# .Net Web API - Entity Framework - ignore relationships during serialization

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a ASP.Net Web API to expose an existing database for use with handheld devices. I am also relatively new at Web API, EF, and everything else I'm trying to use on this project :)

I want the resulting data transfer to be as lightweight as possible but when the api returns an object, the serialized JSON has 'EntityKey' fields for itself and the rows from other tables that the object has a relationship with.

I'm now trying to use the ADO.NET DbContext Template Generator for the model code generation. This gets rid of the EntityKey fields but I still have the relationships showing up in the JSON.

All I want are the fields from the object to be serialized and to be able to deserialize JSON into these objects for inserts and updates. Is there a built-in way to do this?

What's my best bet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your return value "select" a new type

```
return ienumfromedmx.Select(o=> new { id = id, value = value, name = name});
```

where these are the values that you want to return

if you post some example code it might be easier to give you a more relevant code example

using your book

```
public Book GetBook(int id) { return books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);}
```

change to

```
public dynamic GetBook(int id){
return books.SingleOrDefault(b=>b.id == id).Select(new { id = id, Title  = Title, price = Price});
}
```

OR

```
public object GetBook(int id){
return books.SingleOrDefault(b=>b.id == id).Select(new { id = id, Title  = Title, price = Price});
}
```

OR (for reference sake - I'd use dynamic or object for the api rather than a JsonResult)

```
public JsonResult GetBook(int id){
return Json(books.SingleOrDefault(b=>b.id == id).Select(new { id = id, Title  = Title, price = Price}));
}
```

note if you're using

```
public JsonResult GetBook(int id){
return Json(books.SingleOrDefault(b=>b.id == id).Select(new { id = id, Title  = Title, price = Price}));
}
```

and if you're using httpget as opposed to post, then you'd need to use

```
public JsonResult GetBook(int id){
return Json(books.SingleOrDefault(b=>b.id == id).Select(new { id = id, Title  = Title, price = Price},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: so for:
    'public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }'

and the controller:

    'public Book GetBook(int id)
    {
        return books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);   
    }'

How do you change the controller method so that it can return anonymous types?

Comment: change your return type to dynamic so public dynamic GetBook(int id) OR public object GetBook(int id) will also work

Comment: Sorry -the JsonResult is more for std MVC rather than API - I realised after I remembered after I added it that we were talking about API  - didn't want to remove it incase it was helpful

Comment: Thanks for being thorough Brett. I tried them out and they do work, however I think Ladislav's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: And on second thought: Brett's answer will remove all references to relationships (or fields you may not care about) but does require modifying the controllers. Ladislav's answer will still have references to all relationships (although they will be empty json arrays) but you only have to modify the context which you can do globally in the constructor.

So I guess it's a bit of a toss up, good to know about both solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off lazy loading and your method will not return relations unless you explicitly load them with `Include` call:

```
dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
// now load your data and return them to serialization
```

Comment: Does this persist for the session? Or until the context instance is disposed?